# Wired sub query in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables `Recipes` and `Ingredients`, and I have a simple sub query as:

```
SELECT
    RecipeTitle
FROM
    Recipes
WHERE
    Recipes.RecipeID IN (
        SELECT
            RecipeID
        FROM
            Ingredients

    )
```

I wonder why the above sql doesn't have problem, because The `Ingredients` doesn't have `RecipeID` column, so that when I run the following query:

```
    SELECT
        RecipeID
    FROM
        Ingredients
```

Error occurs saying `Unknown column 'RecipeID' in 'field list'`.

Update here:

It won't cause no `Unknown column 'RecipeID' in 'field list'` as below:

```
SELECT
    RecipeTitle
FROM
    Recipes
WHERE
    Recipes.RecipeID/*1*/ IN (
        SELECT
            RecipeID /*no problem if this is the same as 1 in above line*/
        FROM
            Ingredients

    )
```

Comment: Not possible.  If the `Ingredients` table really has no column called `RecipeID`, then both queries should be failing.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, see my update please, it does not fail...

Comment: SQL fiddle can help m replicate this, and hopefully provide an answer

Comment: The error feedback also does not match up with your queries.  Are you sure this is the code you are actually running?

Comment: I am running code as above but sql is throwing error. see this link  http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-in.aspx       http://www.mysqltutorial.org/tryit/query/mysql-in/#4

Comment: Hmm, I believe I have seen this type of question here on SO already

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, I was just doing the test using other columns, and correct my question now

Comment: At this point, you really need to add a demo to your question.  [DBFiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk) is one option.

Comment: I found the same question with answer on the dba site: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/218871/subquery-gives-no-error-for-a-non-existing-column-with-the-same-name-as-in-the-o

Comment: Like @Shadow says, subqueries can reference columns from outer queries, especially if they're in the `SELECT` or `WHERE` clauses.  You need to check your table definitions.

Comment: Gotcha, found the same question here on SO. See the link to the duplicate question. Although, I prefer the answer on the DBA site.

Comment: Thanks @Shadow. Please post your link as an answer. I believe a lot of people should be surprised to see this behavior.

Comment: @Tom I have already found the same question here on SO, so hammered your question as duplicate.

Comment: Sure, thanks all the guys' help,happy new year!